# How can I use globally installed CV2 (manual install) package into python virtual environment?

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv, python-venv

I have manually installed CV2 on Ubuntu box, and when I import CV2 it works perfectly.
If I create virtual environment (`python -m venv myvenv`), I am not able to use globally installed CV2.
Kindly advice the fix, to use global installed packages into python virtual environment.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2 as cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

Comment: have you installed opencv-python for the virtual environment? And why do you need to use the globally installed opencv?

Comment: Is not opencv-python a separate copy of CV2 for virtual-environment?

Comment: It is like any other python library that you can use with any python environment!